# Using interpolation with html-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, string-interpolation, html-webpack-plugin

I need to insert values like `${variable}` into my index.html file. I'm using html-webpack-plugin and everything works like it's supposed to until I add in a value like that.

This is for a file that will go into Marketo so I need to be able to use variables like that inside of a style tag that lives on that page. The variables aren't javascript, but I think this is a javascript issue so I've put them in a script tag for now to help troubleshoot the issue.

**index.html**:

```
<script>
    var x = "John"
    var y = `hello, ${x}`
</script>
```

**config for html-webpack-plugin:**

```
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin(      
    {
        title: 'Index',
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'src/index.html',
        inject: true,
    }
)
```

When I try to compile the page with that syntax on the page, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in Template execution failed: ReferenceError: x is not defined

ERROR in   ReferenceError: x is not defined

  - index.html:100
    /Users/vernb/Code/src/index.html:100:    10

  - index.html:103 ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html.module.exports
    /Users/vernb/Code/src/index.html:103:    3

  - index.js:284 Promise.resolve.then
    [lps-the-good-one]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:284:18

  - next_tick.js:68 process._tickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7
```